# Как считать отдельные столбцы при помощи pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, txt

Нужно считать файл, состоящий из двух столбцов, и прозвести арифметическую операцию. При попытке дать имя столбцу и считать его программа загоняет в это имя весь файл. Второй столбец просто остается пустым (Nan).

```
table = pd.read_table('phases.dat', sep='\t', names = ['files', 'phases'])

files = table['files']
phases = table['phases'].to_numpy()
phases = phases+0.25 

f = open('phases', 'w')
for i in range(len(phases)):
    f.write(str(phases[i])+"  "+files[i]+"\n")
f.close()
```

Я подозреваю, что дело в разделителях в самом txt файле - выставлял нужное количество пробелов, перемещал имена столбцов в разные места, но не помогло.

Сам файл имеет вот такой вид:

```
                 files         phases 
S18421304bctneftxt.txt         0.000000 
S18421305bctneftxt.txt         0.057520 
S18421306bctneftxt.txt         0.114714 
S18421307bctneftxt.txt         0.171091 
S18421308bctneftxt.txt         0.227468 
S18421309bctneftxt.txt         0.284662 
S18421310bctneftxt.txt         0.341038 
S18421311bctneftxt.txt         0.397415 
S18421404bctneftxt.txt         0.537295 
S18421405bctneftxt.txt         0.596450 
S18421406bctneftxt.txt         0.652663 
S18421407bctneftxt.txt         0.709040 
S18421408bctneftxt.txt         0.766234 
S18421409bctneftxt.txt         0.822448 
S18421410bctneftxt.txt         0.878824 
S18421411bctneftxt.txt         0.936672 
S18421412bctneftxt.txt         0.993049 
S18421413bctneftxt.txt         1.049262 
S18421414bctneftxt.txt         1.107273 
S18421415bctneftxt.txt         1.163650 
S18421416bctneftxt.txt         1.219863 
S18421417bctneftxt.txt         1.277057 
S18421418bctneftxt.txt         1.334414 
S18421419bctneftxt.txt         1.390954
```

В чем может быть проблема при считывании?

Comment: у Вас sep='\t' , а между значениями просто множественные пробелы. Если смотреть на то, что выложено сюда.

Comment: между \t и восемью пробелами есть существенная разница...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, проблема в неправильно указанном разделителе столбцов.

Можно использовать регулярное выражение в качестве разделителя столбцов:

```
df = pd.read_csv("phases.dat", sep="\s+")
```

или так:

```
df = pd.read_csv("phases.dat", delim_whitespace=True)
```